# Reactjs Ant-Design Menu - Submenu doesn't pop out

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have used Reactjs Ant-Design Menu in my react project.
I got stucked at one point. 
When i login into my website in mobile view and click on submenu of Ant-Design menu.
It is not clickable until we click out on screen ,other menu-items are working properly,
Please help me out if anyone having any solution for this.
That's my code :

```
          <Menu
            theme="dark"
            mode="inline"
            defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}
            defaultSelectedKeys={[selectedKey]}
          >
           <Menu.Item key="1" >
              <Icon type="dashboard" />
              <span>dashboard</span>
              <Link to="/home" />
            </Menu.Item>
            <SubMenu
              key="sub1"
              title={
                <span>
                  <Icon type="user" />
                  <span>account</span>
                </span>
              }
            >                
              <Menu.Item key="2">
                <Icon type="line-chart" />
                <span>subscriptions</span>
                <Link to="/subscriptions" />
              </Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Item key="3">
                <Icon type="transaction" />
                <span>transactions</span>
                <Link to="/transactions" />
              </Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Item key="4">
                <Icon type="profile" />
                  <span>profile</span>
                  <Link to="/profile" />
              </Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Item key="5">
                <Icon type="key" />
                  <span>password</span>
                  <Link to="/password" />
              </Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>

            <Menu.Item key="7" >
              <Icon type="question-circle" />
              <span>Help</span>
              <Link to="/help" />
            </Menu.Item>

            <Menu.Item key="8" onClick={this.logOut}>
              <Icon type="upload" />
              <span>logout</span>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap link outside icon and text like this to every menu item in your code.

```
 <Link to="/subscriptions">
    <Icon type="line-chart" />
     <span>subscriptions</span>
    </Link>
```